# Distributing a Flutter app using fastlane and Firebase App Distribution

Tags: firebase, flutter, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I distributed a Flutter app using fastlane and Firebase App Distribution. I needed to distribute it again so I incremented the build number in pubspec.yaml file: `version: 1.0.0+1 => 1.0.0+2` and Xcode's `Build: 1 => 2` and ran git commit and ran fastlane command but the new version of release file wasn't uploaded on App Distribution.

What am I missing?

```
[18:38:59]: ------------------------------
[18:38:59]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[18:38:59]: ------------------------------
[18:38:59]: Driving the lane 'android development' 
[18:38:59]: ---------------------------------------
[18:38:59]: --- Step: firebase_app_distribution ---
[18:38:59]: ---------------------------------------
[18:38:59]: Authenticating with FIREBASE_TOKEN environment variable
[18:38:59]:  Authenticated successfully.
[18:39:01]: ✅ This APK has been uploaded before. Skipping upload step.
[18:39:02]: ✅ Posted release notes.
[18:39:03]: ✅ Added testers/groups.
[18:39:03]:  App Distribution upload finished successfully.

+------+---------------------------+-------------+
|                fastlane summary                |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                    | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform          | 0           |
| 2    | firebase_app_distribution | 3           |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+

[18:39:03]: fastlane.tools finished successfully
```

Comment: Try to update to `1.0.1+2` instead of `1.0.0+2`

Answer (score 0):

Then build the Android apk in release as shown below:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Now for deployment, you have to run the fastlane workflow:

```
cd android && fastlane deploy && cd -
```

[android/fastlane/Fastfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jw5g.png)

[For more details](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/flutter-apps-android)